# The map() function returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

While creating a bot I came across something like this

```
// --- index.js ---
[
MessageReaction {
  message: Message {
    [...]
},
users: ReactionUserManager {
  cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
  cache: Collection [Map] {}, // <-- there
  reaction: [Circular]
},
_emoji: ReactionEmoji {
  [...]
},
[...]
 }
]

// --- command.js ---
[
MessageReaction {
  message: Message {
    [...]
},
users: ReactionUserManager {
  cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
  cache: [Collection [Map]], // <-- there
  reaction: [Circular]
},
_emoji: ReactionEmoji {
  [...]
},
[...]
  }
]
```

index.js `cache: Collection [Map] {},`
command.js `cache: [Collection [Map]],`

In index.js, I need to fetch users from `MessageReaction`, but cannot do this via the `map()` function because I am getting an empty array

```
[...code]

let users
for(const u of reactions){
  if(u.emoji.name == ""){
    users = u.users.cache.map(u => u)
    reacLen = u.count - 1
  }
}
console.log(users) // Log -> []
```

Where does this difference come from?
How can I get the user array now?

Comment: Have you enabled all necessary intents? I had an issue where collected reactions returned empty, enabling the intent fixed the issue

Comment: Yes, I have such `const client = new Client ({partials: [" MESSAGE "," REACTION "]}, { ws: { intents: new Intents(Intents.ALL)}})` only that it doesn't change anything